# firebase Crashlytics ndk symbols is missing

Tags: firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics

I want to check the crash log on `android NDK`.

I initialized fabric like this:

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                        .kits(new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())
                        .debuggable(true) // Enables Crashlytics debugger
                        .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

and set up gradle with `crashlytics(2.9.1)`, `crashlytics-ndk(2.0.2)`.

log was successfully added, but all symbol was missing.

so I added `crashlyticsUploadSymbols` to my gradle app, but it has an error.

```
ERROR - Crashlytics Developer Tools error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: null. 
Check the Crashlytics plugin to make sure that the application has been added successfully!
```

how can I upload symbols to firebase? Or is there is another way to see the symbols?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here, do you have any references to Fabric in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: no, I don't have any references to fablic in manifest.

Comment: Ok, so just to confirm, you're trying to setup Crashlytics NDK within Firebase and Firebase alone?

Comment: That's right. But I found a problem :( I used a older version of Fabric Gradle Plugin(1.24.1).  So I updated plugin(1.25.2), there is no problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Firebase here. If you're seeing this issue, please make sure you're running the Fabric gradle plugin 1.25.1 or higher which added this support. From the release [notes](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#id62):

> 1.25.1: December 4, 2017 Enabled native symbol upload for apps using Crashlytics via Firebase.